# I have code that runs fine in jquery mobile 1.0 but not in 1.4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to know what changes to the code would make it work in jqm 1.4.2 
The code is from a book I'm reading on JQuery Mobile written way back in 2012.  This examole workd fine when I use jqm ver 1.0 but breaks using version 1.4.2.
the code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href ="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"/> -->
        // <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> -->
        // <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> -->
        <meta name ="viewport" content ="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role ="page">
        <div data-role ="header">
            <h1> Dynamic page </h1>
            </div> 
        <div data-role ="content">
                <a id="button1" href ="javascript:addPages()"data-role ="button"> Add Pages </a>
                <ul id="list1">
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script>
function addPages() {
 for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var page = $("<div>").jqmData("role", "page").attr("id", "page" + i); 
    // header 
    $("<div>").attr("data-role", "header").append($("<h1>").html("Page "+i+"</h1>")).appendTo(page); 


    // content 
      $("<div>").attr("data-role","content").append($("<p>")
        .html("Contents for page " + i)).appendTo(page);
         $("body").append(page);
         $("<li>").append($("<a>").attr("href","#page" + i).html("Go to page" + i)).appendTo("#list1");

         }      
          $("#button1").hide();
 }
    </script>
```

You can copy and run this and it will work fine.  If you comment out the cdn's for css, jquery and jquery.mobile and uncomment the next 3 up to date versions of same.  The headers all show up on one page that only displays for an instant while the content section is the only section to display.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of places to check.

- The binding events in jquery 1.42 changed (see documentation)
- There may be some jquery ajax methods that have changed (depends on your version of jquery)